# React Native Animated interpolate opacity based on multiple values

Tags: css, animation, react-native, react-animated

I have a React Native Animated.view component whose opacity I would like to interpolate based on the scrollview position. However, I want to interpolate the opacity using two values (x and y) instead of one.

```
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            opacity: this.state.scrollX.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 414, 828],
              outputRange: [0, 1, 1]
            })
          },
          {
            opacity: this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
              inputRange: [-168, -167, -166, -85, -84],
              outputRange: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
            })
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Text>Content....</Text>
      </Animated.View>
```

This doesn't work of course because one opacity value overwrites the other, but it makes clear what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Animated.add()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#add) for it.

```
<Animated.View
  style={[
    {
      opacity: Animated.add(scrollX, scrollY).interpolate({
        inputRange: [],
        outputRange: []
      })
    },
  ]}
>
```

Comment: Is there a way to add string values like '14deg' with '23deg' ?